# Inheritance and Super in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, super

I am on Day 3 of learning JavaScript. I came across this code:

```
class B {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    printn() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class A extends B {
    constructor(name, age) {
        super(name);
        this._age = age;
    }

    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }

    printName(){
        return super.printn();
    }
}

let c = new A("Testing", "37");
Console.log(c.printn());
```

Can anybody explain what this code does. What are the constructor and super() keywords? I believe they are for inheritance? I did Google to find some tuts but this seems to be the simplest example, and it came with very little explanation.

I can't get this code to work.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class

Comment: *"I can't get this code to work."* – Why not? What's the issue? As for the "what does this do" part of the question… It's very basic OOP, which surely has been explained many times before. How are you approaching your learning of Javascript? Perhaps you need a more structured course/tutorial/book. If you're on day 3 of programming in general (?), then yes, OOP may be a bit early to tackle. It won't be productive for you or anyone here if you ask these piecemeal questions which really should be introduced to you in a structured manner.

Comment: I recommend to read http://eloquentjavascript.net and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS (more technical but very good) to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the constructor and super() keyword. I believe it is for inheritance?

That's right. The above sets up class `B` and then has class `A` subclass it. The `constructor` is the function called when you create a new instance of the class, as in the `let c = new A("Testing", "37");` line in the code. Unlike some other languages, in JavaScript there can only be one constructor for a class.

`super` is used in subclasses to refer to the superclass. In a constructor, you *call* `super` as though it were a function, and that calls the superclass's constructor function, giving it a chance to do its initialization of the new object that was created by `new`. So for instance, in `A`'s `constructor`, `super()` calls `B`'s `constructor`.

You can also use `super` as the source of a property accessor expression to access properties (including methods) on the superclass. That's what's happening  in `A`'s `printName` method, where it uses `super.printName()` to call `B`'s `printName` method. (Which will fail, because `B` doesn't have a `printName` method; `B`'s method is called `printn`.)

I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that although this looks a lot like the class-based OOP in, say, Java or C#, it isn't. It's syntactic sugar (the good kind of sugar) for setting up JavaScript's normal *prototypical* inheritance using constructor functions. It hugely simplifies setting up prototypical inheritance hierarchies using constructor functions. I'd also be remiss if I didn't point out that using constructor functions to do prototypical inheritance is not necessary, you can do prototypical inheritance without using constructor functions via `Object.create`.

There's a lot more to explore. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) is probably a good starting point.

> I can't get this code to work.

The `C` in `Console.log` shouldn't be capitalized, so change

```
Console.log(c.printn());
```

to

```
console.log(c.printn());
```

Other than that, if you're using a JavaScript engine that supports `class` (such as the one in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox), that code works fine although note again that `A` seems to expect `B` to have a `printName` method, but it doesn't, and the code at the end is calling `printn` which only `B` has (which is fine, it just means `A`'s code isn't really involved).

```js
class B {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    printn() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class A extends B {
    constructor(name, age) {
        super(name);
        this._age = age;
    }

    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }

    printName(){
        return super.printName();
    }
}

let c = new A("Testing", "37");
console.log(c.printn());
```

Comment: Your words just flowed into my brain. Awesome. Let me process this information and I will ask more questions if I have them. Thanks so much Sir.

Comment: I believe versions prior to ES6 didn't have classes so they used Prototypes. What is protype inheritance and how will I write the same code in it? Can you explain it and how classes solve the problem Prototypes had?

Comment: If you read T.J. Crowder's answer again, you will see that JavaScript hasn't actually changed. ES2015 has just introduced a new way of working with the existing prototypical inheritance model.

Comment: @IGDev: As Ben points out above, I edited in a bit about that. It's still prototypical inheritance, it's (almost) just simpler syntax for setting it up. My other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819733/js-oo-pattern-with-prototype-and-base-class/13819836#13819836) demonstrates `class` syntax and the way you'd accomplish effectively the same thing before `class` syntax (e.g., in ES5 and earlier).

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any post explaining Modules in ES6 too?

Comment: @IGDev: No, but there are several blog posts about it, such as this Mozilla Hacks article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please can you clarify what is the "almost" in "(almost) just a simpler syntax"? My knowledge on classes is weak...

Comment: @BenAston: Methods (on classes and on objects) have a somewhat surprising feature: They have a bulit-in link to the object they were created on (their [[HomeObject]]), and use that to handle `super` -- even if you've copied the method to an entirely different object. You can do everything `class` does in ES2015 without using `class`, but that part of it isn't something that ES5 had, so there's the tiniest thing there which isn't purely syntactic sugar on ES5 mechanisms (although it is on ES2015 mechanisms).

Comment: @BenAston: For clarity: This object has a method called `foo` assigned to a property called `foo`: `const obj = { foo() { } };`. *This* object, though, just has a *function* called `foo` assigned to a property called `foo`: `const obj = { foo: function() { } };`. In the latter case, there is no [[HomeObject]] set up, so `foo` wouldn't be able to use `super` (whereas in the first case, it can; it could use `super.toString()` to do `Object.prototype.toString.call(this)`, for instance).

Comment: @BenAston: Also, FWIW, methods defined via the class syntax cannot be called with `new`. Not that anyone *should* do that, but it's still behavior that deviates from the good old `X.prototype.foo = function() {}`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to JavaScript. Good luck on your journey. I will recast your question from your specific issues to the more general question of how best to learn JavaScript.

First, make sure you've organized your environment, starting with your editor or IDE. Whichever one you choose, it should help you format, indent, highlight, check, and possibly even run your code. Spend time learning how to configure it to your liking. Install useful plug-ins. You will spend many hours in your IDE. Take the same care to furnish it as you would your house.

Next, make sure you understand where to find information. Some people on SO seem to think that it is a human-powered documentation service. MDN is almost always the best resource. They also provide tutorials, which would be a fine place to start.

Next, get very familiar with Chrome devtools. Read the documents from beginning to end. Learn how to use the console, and the source panel, and breakpoints, and variable watches. At the end of the day, you have to debug your own programs, although some people on SO seem to think they can depend on the community to do that.

Now on to the language itself. Before diving into classes, if you haven't already I'd make sure you are very comfortable with the basics: data types including objects and arrays, and basic control structures like conditionals and loops. You should understand exactly what an object is, what a property is, how to write objects in literal form, how to set and retrieve properties, and the equivalent concepts for arrays. Continuously write little programs to try things out; you can run them in the devtools console.

Make sure you have a solid understanding of functions. **They are the fundamental building blocks of JS logic**. They are parameterized bundles of logic that take well-defined inputs (parameters) and produce well-defined outputs (return values). Learn how to define functions, and how to call them. When you approach a problem, it is almost always a good starting point to think about how it can be broken down into sub-problems that can be implemented as functions.

Once you are comfortable with arrays and functions, make sure you have a firm grasp of the array methods (functions) which take functions as parameters. That's right; in JavaScript, functions are values which can be passed to other functions as parameters. This is your first gentle introduction to functional programming. Learn `forEach` and related array methods, where you pass a function to tell it what to do with each element.

If you are doing front-end work, you will need to be very familiar with the DOM. Go back to devtools and make sure you understand how to examine the DOM using the Elements panel. Learn the basic DOM APIs for creating elements, setting their attributes, inserting them into the DOM, and finding them in the DOM, such as `getElementById`. Again, as you go along, continuously write little sample programs to confirm that you are on the right track and reinforce your knowledge. In tandem with mastering the DOM, you will need to begin learning CSS, which is the way we manage properties which control how DOM elements are styled (layed out and formatted), and CSS classes, which are bundles of those properties that can be applied by simply assigning a class to an element. Take time to grasp the cascade, which is the process by which the CSS engine decies which rule to apply to which element. Go back to devtools once more and make sure you understand how to examine CSS properties in the DOM using the style inspector.

You'll notice that we haven't even mentioned JS classes yet, which is what your question here is about. I'm a little surprised that you would be delving into this topic so early in your learning process. Classes are the foundation of a particular style of program design generally known as object-oriented programming, or classical OOP, which involves designing objects which are bundles of data and related functionality. There are people who believe that all programming is, or should be, OOP. There are other people who successfully write large systems without using any OOP principles at all.

The problem with OOP is that the real world does not divide itself neatly into Animals and Dogs and Vehicles and Cars and As and Bs. After you've defined Animals and Dogs then you realize that you need Mammals in between, and before you know it you end up with a contorted class hierarchy that is hard to understand, maintain, and extend, and which you spend half your time re-arranging. It's quite likely that none of this machinery is going to be necessary for the IRL problems you are trying to solve. Once you have the OOP hammer, everything starts looking like a nail. Before long you will be pounding with your new OOP hammer on strands of limp spaghetti and blobs of jello, or simply waving it in the air.

Comment: Nitpick - I would describe using classes as "classical OOP" and not simply "OOP". I believe JavaScript without classes can be described as OOP (although whether it meets Kay's definition including message passing I'm not sure). I fully agree with your point about mixing functionality and data and this is why I personally believe classes are actively harmful to good code. In short it is not OOP that is harmful, but (IMHO) the classical style.

Comment: Thank you @torazaburo . I will follow the advice.