# What is Super(props) for? React Native

Tags: react-native, super

While experimenting with React Native and using States. I came against super(props). I searched here in the forum for a useful explaination, but I didn't find any.

Here is a look on the function, where I am using super and constructor...
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C69Fi.png)

I tried to delete props parameter in constructor, but it gave me an error. Then I tried to delete super(props), it gave me again an error. However, the code perfectly work, when I just used super() without parameter.

My conclusion is, in constructor i am saying we are using props and with super I am allowing an access over all props globally in code?

I am not really sure, correct me please If I am wrong.

I appreciate any comments with advises. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I also added the rest of the code...For a clear undestanding..
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2gH.png)

I appreciate your help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance and Super in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180655/inheritance-and-super-in-javascript)

Comment: Did you try googling e.g. "super javascript"?

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I did, but somehow I think my case here is different. It would be helpful if you could explain :)

Comment: `super` by itself calls the parent class constructor on the current instance with the supplied parameters and must be called in every subclass prior to the first use of `this`.

Comment: @JaredSmith but if I don't want to use this, I don't need to load props in super, right? What also weird is that I can use 'this' in render in my subclass even if super isn't loaded with props. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React Native when using `super(props)` you can immediately access the props via `this.props` in the constructor while with only `super()` you can't.

In other methods like `render` however you can always utilize `this.props`.

Here is a complete examples of the explaination above:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995257/4293498

Comment: I see. This make total sense. Thanks for the help!